# Clear upload area in Vue2-Dropzone

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-dropzone

I'm currently working on Laravel Vue SPA admin panel. And I've applied Vue2-Dropzone to upload images for the gallery section.

In this project the vue2-dropzone form opens on a bootstrap model.

My codes successfully uploads the images. When I close the model and reopen it to upload other images it shows the thumbnails of previously uploaded images.

Below is my code snippet:

```js
import vue2Dropzone from "vue2-dropzone";
import "vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dropzoneOptions: {
        url: "/api/carousel",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg',
        dictDefaultMessage: "Click or Drag and Drop to upload",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]")
            .content
        }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    newModal() {
      vue2Dropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
    }
  },
  components: {
    vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
  }
};
```

With the above code I get the following error after clicking the add image button that opens the model to upload images:

> app.js:84606 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue2_dropzone___default.a.removeAllFiles is not a function
>   at VueComponent.newModal (app.js:84606)
>       at invoker (app.js:54930)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:54729)

I want to clear the thumbnails of previously uploaded images from dropzone modal.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have vue-dropzone with ref in template

```
 <vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone" id="dropzone">
 </vue-dropzone>
```

then you should use

```
  this.$refs.myVueDropzone.removeAllFiles()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd find the solution in Vue2-Dropzone closed issue also.

Answer (score 0):

The `removeAllFiles()` is kind of a hack. It won't work for some cases.

For example, it will not 'reset' the Dropzones' `options` object. So if you want to do validations for diferent cases via the options object, it will not reset with the `removeAllFiles()` method.

The right way to reset the Dropzone (or any Vue object in that matter) is to set and change the `:key` attribute. Like this for example:

```
<vue-dropzone :key="`dropzone-${dynamicVariableOrJustSomeCounter}`">
</vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: works half.   if use `this.$refs.dropz.manuallyAddFile(el, el.url)` duplic template prevew. my point how can I to restart or clean dropzone